# Software for making semi variograms and analyses?

Tags: references, spatial, software, interpolation, variogram

Our lab used to have a program called GS+ that let us make semi variograms on our data and analyse them. Unfortunately, the licence has expired.

Is there another piece of software that lets you do this? If so, how specifically? We prefer a free and open source licence, but all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: did you have a look at those statistic software alternatives: http://statpages.org/javasta2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides R, here are a few links that may be of interest that do not appear to be on the AI Geostats page:

- [SpaceStat](http://www.biomedware.com/?module=Page&sID=spacestat) (not free)
- [Passage software](http://www.passagesoftware.net/index.php) (haven't tried it, looks like it has functionality you stated in your question plus some more)
- [High performance Geostat library](http://hpgl.aoizora.org/index.php) (looks like GUI is in the works, but only beta versions of it are available)
- [SAM (Spatial Analysis in Macroecology)](http://www.ecoevol.ufg.br/sam/). It has a kriging module so I assume it must allow you to estimate the semi-variogram.
- Pierre Goovaerts has a [book chapter review on Geostatistical software](http://home.comcast.net/~pgoovaerts/A7-June.pdf) publicly listed on his website. (A note, he works for the makers of the above SpaceStat software, so unsurprisingly he gives it glowing reviews.)

The book, [A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/), has relevent examples using R and Google Earth (of course R is used to estimate the variograms).

Comment: +1 Good finds.  The Goovaerts chapter briefly reviews almost all the software listed in the AI-Geostats site.

Answer (score 5):

The most comprehensive list has long been maintained at the [AI Geostats pages](http://www.ai-geostats.org/bin/view/AI_GEOSTATS/SoftwareGeostatistical): it includes freeware and commercial software (almost 30 free ones).  That page has a [separate link](http://www.ai-geostats.org/bin/view/AI_GEOSTATS/SoftwareCodes) to add-ons, such as any R packages.

AFAIK, there is no R package for handling 3D variography or change of support problems.  The R packages are also weak at modeling rich datasets, which often need nested models with varying anisotropy and variogram shapes.  For good integration of variography, kriging, simulation, EDA, and statistical modeling, though, the R packages are excellent.

Answer (score 4):

package `geoR` for `R` could be what you're looking for. From the documentation:

"function `variogram` Computes sample (empirical) variograms with options for the classical or robust estimators. Output can be returned as a binned variogram, a variogram cloud or a smoothed variogram. Data transformation (Box-Cox) is allowed. “Trends” can be specified and are fitted by ordinary least squares in which case the variograms are computed using the residuals."

Also `variofit`: "Estimate covariance parameters by fitting a parametric model to a empirical variogram. Variograms models can be fitted by using weighted or ordinary least squares."

There are more geostatistical packages in `R`.

Answer (score 1):

The [R](http://www.r-project.org/) program is free and open source, there are functions in the nlme package for R that do semi-variograms (and probably other options as well, but nlme came up in a quick search).